# Invalid Thread Access when create a Vaadin Composite

Tags: vaadin

I followed the steps in http://vaadin.com/eclipse :

> You can create a CustomComponent based compositions and edit them with
>   the visual designer tool included with the plug-in.
>
> Select File -> New -> Other... Select Vaadin Composite from the dialog
>   Click on the Design tab below the code editor to switch to the visual
>   designer

But the eclipse throws the:

> Invalid Thread Access

error.

I searched this issue into vaadin, but the one related was https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/665040 and it wasn't useful for me.

Someone knows how to correct this problem?

Jas

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the class file you are trying to create already exists. If so, you can right click on it in the Project Explorer and say "**Open With -> Vaadin Editor**" to access the visual designer tab. Or try "**File -> New - > Other -> Vaadin Composite**" but use a different package or class name.

(The first time I used the Vaadin composite wizard I got an error that Mozilla XULRunner was not installed. After installing it, I tried to create the composite again and got the same "Invalid thread access" error that you received. Of course, it turned out that the component already existed and I was trying to create a duplicate, hence the (unhelpful) error.)